# How to find average rating of a gig from another reviews model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two Django Models 'Gigs' and 'Reviews' I want to get an average of the ratings belonging to that Gigs field. I also want the avg_rating on the movie field to update every time a review is added. Im new to Django and I've tried alot but I don't really know what the error is. Below is my code files

**Models.py**

```
class Gigs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    details = models.TextField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        if self._average_rating is not None:
            return self._average_rating
        return self.reviews.aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating_avg']

class Reviews(models.Model):
    rating = models.SmallIntegerField( default=0,validators=[MaxValueValidator(5),MinValueValidator(1)])
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Gigs , on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User ,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class GigsListAll(GenericAPIView, ListModelMixin ):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Gigs.objects.all().annotate(_average_rating=Avg('reviews__rating'))
    serializer_class = GigsSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request , *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class GigsSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    average_rating = serializers.FloatField()
    class Meta:
        model = Gigs
        fields = ['id','title','category','price','details','seller','images', 'average_rating']
```

But when I tried to go to my this **Api** it gives me an error

**"Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `average_rating` on serializer `GigsSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Gigs` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'rating_avg'."**

Comment: remove the `average_rating` from the `fields`, only specify it in the serializer.

Comment: then it gives error (Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `average_rating` on serializer `GigsSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Gigs` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Gigs' object has no attribute 'average_rating'.)

Comment: and replace `if self._average_rating is not None:` with `if hasattr(self, '_average_rating')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a SerializerMethodField to serialize properties. Your serializer should look like:

```
class GigsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    average_rating = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_average_rating(self, obj):
        return obj.average_rating

    class Meta:
        model = Gigs
        fields = ["""your fields here"""]
```

To get the value for a SerializerMethodField the serializer look for a method named get_ in order to compute its value. The get_ method, accept an object that's going to be the serialized object (a Gigs instance in this case)